# Multi-Project Nuget Issues

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, nuget, nuget-package

I have a multi-project ASP.NET 4.0 Web Forms solution. Initially I created a project package consisting of static files: master, css, images, etc.

I have since upgraded to Nuget 1.4 to avail of a solution project (so I don't have to manually update each project). I planned to uninstall existing project package, then create and install a solution package containing the same common files.

After running Uninstall-Package MyProjectPackage, I noticed that there are still Nuget-related files in my projects. For example:

### Project 1:

packages.config
Packages.dgml
MyProjectPackage.1.1.nuspec
MyProjectPackage.1.2.nupkg

### Project 2:

MyProjectPackage.nuspec

**Issues:**

1. They are greyed-out like they are not included in the solution
   anymore, but these files are still in the project folders. Should
   they not have been totally removed?
2. I have created a new package using the GUI. What is the correct way to install this for the solution?
3. How do I add NuGet to my path? (getting "The term 'nuget' is not recognized..." on command line)

**UPDATE 08-24-2011:**

I created a new solution package and added it via the Package Manager Settings. Unfortunately, when I install it, it is not being pushed out to sub-project. Cannot get this to work.

**UPDATE 08-25-2011:**

In an effort to narrow this down, when I try to Manage Installed Package at the solution level, I cannot get to the "Select Projects GUI" because there is no "Manage" button, only an "Uninstall" button, in the 'MyProject.sln - Manage NuGet Packages' dialog.

Package Contents (basic structure for brevity):

controls (Folder)
- Footer.ascx
- Footer.ascx.cs
- Footer.ascx.designer.cs

images (Folder)
- footer.jpg

masters (Folder)
- Site.Master 
- Site.Master.cs
- Site.Master.designer.cs

style (Folder)
- style.css

Comment: What do you mean "solution package"?

Comment: Prior to 1.4 release, packages were project-based; I would have had to push out a package to each project in the solution. In this release I can apply package to every project in the solution: http://bit.ly/oG9UMQ

Comment: That's not true. Packages can still target projects, we just added the ability to manage packages at solution level. So your package should definitely target a project still.

Comment: I realize that. The solution I'm working on will have 21 projects, so I need to learn how to package these correctly and push them "once" to every project in the solution... :)

Comment: All you need to do is use the project package you had from before, select the solution level dialog, click install, and select all 21 projects.

Comment: How do I get to the solution dialog?

Comment: Right click on the solution and click "Manage NuGet Packages"

Comment: Sounds like what I already did, but will give it another shot tomorrow. Thanks David :)

Comment: Not working. Not uninstalling. Not being pushed out to other project with a new install, etc. http://bit.ly/p4PQub What files should be removed with an uninstall - docs are sketchy.

Comment: What is in your package? i.e. What's the structure?

Comment: David, I've updated the question with package structure.

Comment: Are those files in the root content folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the structure you have, you need to put everything in a content/ for it to apply to a project.

More information here:
http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package#From_a_convention_based_working_directory

Comment: Thanks David, really appreciate you help on this :)